# Как узнать к какому Reference относится та или иная библиотека

Tags: c#, winforms, dll

В папке bin/Release по итогу оказывается множет dll+xml в связке. Каким образом можно узнать к какому Reference относится каждая dll?

По идее сколько References столько и dll должно быть в каталоге bin/Release, так? У меня же это не так: дополнительно создаются другие dll, которые как-то имеют отношение к References. Но как выявить это отношение?

Спасибо!

P.S. Я использую сторонние компоненты (DevExpress), но вопрос всё же общий.

Comment: полная информация по всем файлам, которые используются в проекте, включая сборки, находится в файле с расширением .csproj, посмотрите мой ответ.

Comment: А DevExpress Assembly Deployment Tool разве не показывает?

Comment: Насколько я понимаю, references работают рекурсивно: если проект требует одну dll, а эта dll требует наличия другой, то другая тоже подгружается.

Comment: Возможно. Но как узнать это наверняка? Ведь DL-зависимость должна быть где-то видна, но её нет.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В свойствах каждой Reference есть параметр CopyLocal. Если true - то соотв. дллка будет скопирована при компиляции в папку с бинарниками. Также туда попадут файлы которые добавлены в проект и в свойствах которых соответствующим образом установлено значение поля 'Copy to Output Directory', например это могут быть сторонние дллки, которые необходимы твоему приложению или другие файлы, например локальная база данных. Также в свойствах проекта в разделе 'Build Events' есть поля для записи скриптов выполняемых до и после компиляции. И там вполне могут быть инструкции копирования файлов (любых, куда угодно).
И еще различные производители для локализации используют ресурсные дллки (по каждому языку), например производители контролов - точно. Эти дллки (или даже папки с дллками) в итоге тоже попадают в папку с бинарниками

Answer (score 2):

Если проект создан в Visual Studio, то у проекта есть файл названиепроекта.csproj 
Это обычный xml. Откройте его в любом текстовом редакторе.
В нем есть теги Reference и бывают COMReference. 
В некоторых из тегов Reference указаны имена dll файлов, часть из которых соответствует файлам в \bin\Release.

.NET-сборку (dll или exe) можно открыть в ildasm.exe и посмотреть зависимости.

Comment: если у вас нет копий этих файлов, то скопируйте. после этого в Visual Studio вызовите контекстное меню проекта и надо выбрать Clean. и после этого Build. что теперь в \bin\Release - также как было или меньше?

Comment: Ничего не изменилось.

Comment: а в Solution только один проект?

Comment: Только один. Я не исключаю, что просто одни dll требуют наличие других, поэтому так и получается. Но как это точно узнать? Я скачал даже спец. утилиту Dependacy Walker - но она не показала то, что я ожидал увидеть.

Comment: зависимости вписаны прямо в dll -- добавил в ответ.

Comment: Просмотрел, никаких связей не нашел.

Answer (score 2):

1. Открываете узел References, выбираете сборку, в контекстном меню жмете на Properties.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

2. В открывшейся вкладке Properties смотрите на имя файла в свойстве
   Path.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Это не показывает полную зависимость от dll. Дополнил информацию в вопросе.